# while adding two number if user enter string how to restrict him

Tags: c#

Here i'm writing a simple c#program Addding two number but if user Enter string sting value how to say him Enter only integer value

```
 int x;
 int y;
 int result;
 string Res2;
 Console.Write("\n Enter the first number to be added: ");
 x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.Write("\n Enter the second number to be added: ");
 y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 if (x != null && y != null)
 {
      result = x + y;
      Console.Write("\n The sum of two numbers is: " + result);

 }
```

Comment: use ``int.TryParse`` instead

Comment: [Check this out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yjZ0p3)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32()` always returns an int, it never returns null. Also your variables are int, so they can never be null. So checking for null is useless, for both reasons. Use `int.TryParse(...)`, as others have said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could put something like

```
int x;
Console.Write("\n Enter the first number to be added: ");
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x))
{
    Console.Write("\nPlease, enter a valid number: ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below if you want to continue the program after invalid inputs

```
string x,y;
int a,b;
int result;
bool flag = false;
do{
  if(flag)
  Console.Write("\n Please enter integer values");

  Console.Write("\n Enter the first number to be added: ");
  x = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.Write("\n Enter the second number to be added: ");
  y = Console.ReadLine();

  flag = true;
  }
  while(!int.TryParse(x, out a) || !int.TryParse(y, out b));

  if (x != null && y != null)
  {
     result = a + b;
     Console.Write("\n The sum of two numbers is: " + result);
  }
```